# What are stream and readStream functions in Databricks DLT SQL?

Tags: spark-streaming, azure-databricks, databricks-sql, delta-live-tables

In the Databricks Delta Live Table documentations, I saw some `stream()` and ˙readStream()˙ calls in SQL code examples. But I can't figure out what are these, what's the difference. Are those functions documented anywhere?

While `spark.readStream` exists in Python/Scala/Java/R, I couldn't find any SQL examples. So how to use it, what are the parameters? Sometimes `stream()` also works in SQL, is it just an alias to `readStream()` which is an alias to `spark.readStream()` in Python?

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is an alias for reading delta stream table.

```
dlt.read_stream()
```

Below, the code creates a delta live table from cloud files.

```py
@dlt.table
def streaming_bronze():
  return (
    # Since this is a streaming source, this table is incremental.
    spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
      .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")
      .load("/path/to/raw/data")
  )
```

To read data from `streaming_bronze`, you write the following code.

```py
@dlt.table
def streaming_silver():
  return dlt.read_stream("streaming_bronze").where(...)
```

If you see here, to read the `streaming_bronze` table, `dlt.read_stream("streaming_bronze")` is used.

The same thing, if you want in the SQL language, the `STREAM` function is used.

```
STREAM(LIVE.streaming_bronze)
```

For more information, follow this [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/transform.html#language-sql).

Next, the alias for `spark.readStream()`, which actually creates delta streaming table using the Python decorator `@dlt.table`, and in SQL is below.

```sql
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING TABLE table_name
AS SELECT * FROM cloud_files(
  "path/to/raw/data", "json"
)
```

This creates a delta streaming table. Then, to read this data again, you use `STREAM(<table_name>)`.

```sql
CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING TABLE streaming_silver
AS SELECT * FROM STREAM(LIVE.streaming_bronze)
```

Basically, whenever you want to add data incrementally to streaming table you need
to use `STREAM` function.